# defineCall is not a function, sequelize error

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, sequelize.js

I've been trying to figure out how to fix the following error generated by my index.js file. I'm using Node, Express and sequelize.

```
/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:691
server_1       |     this.importCache[path] = defineCall(this, DataTypes);
server_1       |                              ^
server_1       | 
server_1       | TypeError: defineCall is not a function
```

The error is, as I understand it generated because I'm importing something that's not a sequelize model to my index.js file (see below for the index.js code). But I simply cannot find where the problem lies. Below is the code. Any help would be much appreciated!

Booking model code:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var config = require('../config');
var db = require('../services/database');
// 1: The model schema.
var modelDefinition = {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
};
// 2: Define the User model.
var BookingModel = db.define('booking', modelDefinition);
// DB relations
BookingModel.associate = (models) => {
   BookingModel.hasMany(models.BookingModel, {});
 };
module.exports = BookingModel;
```

Important part of Index.js file:

```
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequelize model file must be in the format as below,

```
module.exports = function(connection, Sequelize){
  var table = connection.define('table', {
    id : Sequelize.INTEGER,
  });
  return table;
}
```

In the model that you have specified it exports a model definition and that is the reason for error.
sequelize expects every model to export a function that returns a table definition.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because my `index.js` was pulling in my test files as well as the models, which were in the same directory. Make sure there's nothing else in your model directory, or if there are other files (like tests), make sure `index.js` is excluding them when it builds the file list.